# URL query string limit increase in Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: iis-7, web-config, windows-server-2008-web

In my local machine the project works fine, i have the following options inside my web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
```

and

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="false">
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="2097151" maxUrl="10999" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

When i have it on my windows web server 2008 machine it works fine except for the pages with long query strings.

Local Machine Specs:

```
Windows 8
IIS 8.0
```

also tested in another Local Machine with the following Specs:

```
Windows 7
IIS 7.5
```

Server Specs:

```
Windows Web Server 2008
IIS 7.0
```

If any more info is required let me know and i will edit the question.

I've looked into other SO questions and i couldn't find an answer for this, any suggestions?

Comment: added local machine specs